# create new variables within a loop in python

Tags: python

Is it possible to create a program that makes it's own variables within a loop in python?

I want it to make a new variable in iteration from "line 1" to line "15". So, I want the program to create a new variable in iteration within a loop.

For example when the program is run it would make variables called:

```
line1=
line2=
line3=
```

and this would repeat until the loop ends.

In this program the user would select a number of lines, but I don't know how many. And i want the program to create a new variable for each line.

```
while choice != 10:
```

Now the program should make a new variable with different names in iteration until it matches the number of lines selected.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Sounds like a great usecase for a [List](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Answer (score -1):

this loops 5 times and creates the variable x and assigns a value from a user input. I have been having trouble implementing this test into other programs but it should be a starting point.

```
        for i in range(5):
var_name = "x" + str(i)  # create variable name with index
value = input("enter the the value of " + var_name + "--> ")
exec(var_name + " = " + value)  # assign value to variable using exec()
# code after the loop can use the variables 
print(x0,x1,x2,x3,x4)
```

Comment: your code is not indented properly.. format your code.